# How to build the generic form which is not linked to any entity in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

So far , i have only built form which are related to entities using formbuilder

i normally do this

`$builder->add("tasks")`

Then i do this

`$Form   = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $entity);`

Now i just want a generic form where i have the select boxes in which i can load entities from database.

I am not persisting or binding that form i just want that when user select user and hit submit then i go to that user page

IN the above form i used to have tasks as property in user entity so i used add.

But i just want want to display tasks , whichis not linked to user can i do that

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date')
        ->getForm();
```

Example i above code can i do that

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date')
        ->getForm();
```

Comment: Can you create a generic object and put that there?  Like $task = Object()

Comment: @Jake yes but you don't even need to do that

Comment: @Lusi what do you mean , can you give me example

Comment: Based on your question, you probably want to look into the symfony2 "entity" form field type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before reading, why would you show a `<select>` for doing nothing? Maybe there is a better solution to achieve what you want :)

Anyway, if your form has some field not related to an entity property, just set the option `property_path` to `false`. Assuming you want to display a `<select>` ot tasks i would do:

```php
$this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('task', 'entity', array(
        'property_path' => false,
        'class'         => 'Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\Task', // Full/short FQCN
        'property'      => 'name', // Assuming your task as a property "name",
    ))
;
```

And if for some reason you need selected value (mean selected `Task` object) you can get with `$form->get('task')->getData()`, after binding it with the request.